# return dynamic txt (no html) in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application which receives a file as input and only returns a single letter as output (like A, B, C - it is a machine learning classifier and these are classes).

I have a basic application setup using SpringBoot, but I can't figure out how to return values other than as part of a full HTML template.

This works, but it isn't what I want:

mytemplate.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" th:replace="~{fragments/layout :: layout (~{::body},'hello')}">
<body>
<div class="container">
    <p th:text="${my_output}"/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

MyMainClass.java:

```
@RequestMapping("/my_test")
String my_test(Map<String, Object> model) {
    String result;
    ...processing...
    model.put("my_output", result);
    return "mytemplate";
}
```

What I want is just a single letter to be returned, but when I renamed mytemplate.html to mytemplate.txt and had it consist solely of `${my_output}` it just returned that as a literal string, rather than replacing anything. Basically I need a way to either get the template engine to allow me to generate a raw text file like that, or I need to bypass the template engine somehow. I don't know anything about how Spring Boot works or about the template engine yet, so I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this something like this

```
@RequestMapping("/my_test")
public String my_test(HttpServletResponse response) {
  String result;
  ...processing...
  response.setContentType("text/plain");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  return result ;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, unfortunately - in Spring Boot it seems that the return value is interpreted as the name of the template. So the value of `result` is the string "A" then I get the error `Error resolving template "A", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers` because it's looking for an actual template named that.

Comment: The annotation on my class was `@Controller`. When I changed it to `@RestController` the code you provided technically works now (I'm getting the letter back and nothing else). That said, it's still spitting an exception each time, `org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "A"`. So it's still looking for the template somehow.

Comment: I was able to get it to work. Thanks for your initial help. I edited your answer with some additional details and accepted it.